# How to specify a jOOQ data type binding for columns whose name have nothing in common?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

When using jOOQ with PostgreSQL, there is the possibility of using a [custom data type binding](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/), and specify in the code generator to which columns such a binding should apply.

Sometimes, however, those columns have nothing in common, i.e. their names are completely unrelated. Is there an easy way to specify a binding for all those columns?

#### Note:

[The question came up on the jOOQ user manual](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/#comment-2835195080). Reproducing here for better visibility as many jOOQ users have the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a SQL query to produce the list of columns from your database to feed into that regular expression. Something like:

```sql
SELECT string_agg(n.nspname || '\.' || c.relname || '\.' || a.attname, '|')
FROM pg_namespace n
JOIN pg_class c ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
JOIN pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = c.oid
JOIN pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid
WHERE t.typname = 'json'
```

The result of this query can then be fed to jOOQ's code generator configuration